# With Combine how to iterate through an array of dictionaries and set 1 additional property?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, combine

In [a simple test project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/TopsBatchInsert/TopsBatchInsert/ViewModels/TopViewModel.swift) I am downloading JSON file, parse it into `[[String:Any]]` and then would like to pass the data structure to Core Data's `NSBatchInsertRequest`:

```
func fetchTopModels(language:String) {
    guard let url = urls[language] as? URL else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap(handleOutput)
        .tryMap { jsonData -> [[String: Any]] in
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
            guard let jsonDict = json as? [String:Any],
                  let dataList = jsonDict["data"] as? [[String:Any]]
                else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
                return dataList
        }
        // TODO How to set language on each dataList member?
        //.map {
              //$0.language = language
        //}
        .sink { completion in
            print("fetchTopModels completion=\(completion)")
        } receiveValue: { fetchedTops in
            PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask { backgroundContext in
                backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
                backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
                backgroundContext.perform {
                    
                    let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: TopEntity.entity(), objects: fetchedTops)
```

However the `[[String:Any]]` data structure is missing the `language` String property on each of its members. It is mandatory on the Core Data entity.

My question is how to iterate through the array and set the `language` on each member (for example to the value of `"en"`)?

I have searched, but it is difficult to find a good pointer because the search keywords are too common :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the dictionary you need to create a mutable copy of each and insert the language and also a copy of the array itself. Something like this

```
.map { array in
    array.map { dict -> [String: Any] in
        var temp = dict
        temp["language"] = language
        return temp
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ouch I was hoping for an elegant one-liner